# Prestashop: An error has occured: You must install PHP zip extension first. I have Zip extension installed

Tags: php, apache, prestashop-1.7

When i tried to install Prestashop 1.7.6.1 i have the following problem:
[Zip Extension problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXEdr.png)

The error is very clear but the real problem is that i have installed the extension and restarted the server and the problem continues.

PHP -V

[Php -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBsuc.png)

PHP -M

[Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ed0e.png)

I think that is a route problem because if i enter in the following route /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.11/pecl/20180731/  I have de zip.so extension but if i enter in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731 i have only apcache.so and xdebug.so but i dont know how to fix it.

Im in macOS Catalina 10.15.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already install the php packes/resources that are needed in the prestashop 1.7.6? 
And i think they recommended the PHP 7.2 in the current latest prestashop version.
check this official docs: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/

Answer (score 1):

go to Xampp- Apache- config- PHP(php.ini)

ctrl+F `extension=shmop`, paste this below **extension=php_zip.dll**

stop and start server

problem solved - 2023

Comment: Please try to find your own solutions, this way you will help the OP, the community and finally yourself, because your own skills may improve ;) - your answer is a 1/1 duplicate of @mejri-bassem's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75999752), dated April 12, 2023. You may find useful information here: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) / [How to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 0):

How to verify your server meets PrestaShop’s requirements
You can use our system requirements tool to easily check if your environment fulfills PrestaShop’s requirements. Here’s how:

Download the latest version from GitHub.
https://github.com/PrestaShop/php-ps-info/releases

Extract the zip file.
Upload the phppsinfo.php file to your server and put it inside your current shop’s directory or the one where you intend to install it.
Open it up on your browser (http://your-domain.com/path-to-your-prestashop/phppsinfo.php).
Type in the login and password if prompted (use prestashop for both).
You’ll get a web page detailing requirements and recommendations, and how your server does compared to them:

Answer (score 0):

go to Xampp- Apache- config- PHP(php.ini)

ctrl+F EXTENSION
remove semicolone of:
extension=gd
extension=php
stop and start server
problem solved